# What is the canonical way to obtain parameters of a trained classifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Once a scikit-learn classifier is trained:

```py
import sklearn.cluster
clf = sklearn.cluster.KMeans()
clf.fit(X)
```

there are (at least) two options to obtain values of its parameters. Specifically,

1. By referring to a parameter name with a traling underscore:

```py
clf.n_clusters_
```

2. From a dictionary obtained with `get_params()`:

```py
ps = clf.get_params()
ps['n_clusters']
```

Which of these approaches is the preferred one?

Answer (score 2):

I would say `clf.get_params()` because you don't always know what parameters might be available for a given estimator and this method will return everything, unless you know exactly what you are looking for. It also has a `deep` argument which when set to true, "...will return the parameters for this estimator and contained subobjects that are estimators"